# Name of the input/output element must be unique (WSDL Spec)

Tags: xml, web-services, xsd, wsdl, unique

I've posted this question [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/595284/Web-Services/java/Name-input-output-element-must). but didnt get any answers. So I'm posting it here as well.

---

I've a question on the WSDL.

I've a WSDL that has two methods as below:

```
<portType name="TestService">
    <operation name="add">
        <input
            wsam:Action="http://service.psvm.com/testservice/TestService/addRequest"
            message="tns:add"
            name="InputNums" />
        <output
            wsam:Action="http://service.psvm.com/testservice/TestService/addResponse"
            message="tns:addResponse"
            name="Result" />
    </operation>
    <operation name="subtract">
        <input
            wsam:Action="http://service.psvm.com/testservice/TestService/subtractRequest"
            message="tns:subtract"
            name="InputNums" />
        <output
            wsam:Action="http://service.psvm.com/testservice/TestService/subtractResponse"
            message="tns:subtractResponse"
            name="Result" />
    </operation>
</portType>
```

As you can see, both the operations add and subtract have input & output messages with the same names "InputNums" and "Result" respectively.

When I try to validate this WSDL, I get the following error:

> The name 'InputNums' specified for this input element is not unique. 
>   The name of an input element must be unique from the names of all
>   other input and output elements defined in the 'TestService' port
>   type.

I've read the WSDL spec here which doesn't give the reasons clearly(at least to me). It says:

> The name attribute of the input and output elements provides a unique
>   name among all input and output elements within the enclosing port
>   type.  In order to avoid having to name each input and output element
>   within an operation, WSDL provides some default values based on the
>   operation name.

In order to avoid naming each input/output elements, WSDL provides defaults. But why is that a RULE? Shouldn't it be a warning? 
Can't the developer provide the names by him/herself if he/she wants to?

Further, I don't understand why this is a problem, since when the clients invoke the web service, they invoke with specific operation names called 'add' or 'subtract'. 
My question finally is - As long as the operation names are different why should the parameter names matter? 
Can some one please explain the consequences of having the WSDL like this, if any ?

Comment: Something seems to be missing in that gray box.

Comment: I was editing it. Sorry for some reason the WSDL content was not showing up. Can you see it now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that a better answer might come if you would describe `why not?`. What does it do to you if instead you stick with the defaults? And if you want to name them, why not follow the rule?

This is not to say that you are not somewhat right. In fact, WSDL 2.0 dropped this attribute entirely. So I guess that people working on the spec didn't find any evidence in the implementations based on the 1.1 note indicating any practical use of this rule; so in that spirit, they've dropped it, along with the attribute. I am pretty sure that these names have no use even with RPC style bindings.

I could see why, in the early days, someone would put this rule: it is consistent with the rest of the rules for names; and I guess it was argued that subsequent binding specs may find some use for these names being unique.

If someone would argue my point by asking why it wasn't enforced in the XSD for WSDL 1.1, same as other name rules, I would answer that XSD cannot express this constraint (since it is across two different selectors that could match at the same time).

I really think it is important why do you care. All tools that I tested (.NET and JAX-WS) don't really mind it: they're able to do their contract-to-code bindings. WS-I BP 1.x and 2.x doesn't seem to even address it. All of this and seeing WSDL 2.0 dropped it all together, tells you that you are right, it is/was useless.

I also know tools that will not validate a WSDL such as yours; on the other hand, .NET won't even squeak.

Nonetheless, if you care about a validation result that's picky beyond being practical, then you'll just have to stick with the rule... or ignore it.

Comment: Why not?-Well, pain is: I need to provide webservice that has 10 diff methods that take the same set of params(say 20 vars), do some calculation & return same set of params but with updated values. Now, I have put all these 20 vars into a POJO and accepting the same POJO as input and returning the same POJO as output all these 10 methods. The WSDL that I wrote used the same object name for all these parameters. The WSDLvalidation fails with the unique-name constraint. If I use diff.object names for the POJO, then I need to have 10 diff.objects(or 20) that literally will have same 20 variables.

Comment: As, we are following WSDL 1.1 & 3rd party which are the clients for this WSDL won't accept it because it doesn't follow the spec. I had to really spend some time to convince them. Although, it had a happy ending, the pain could have been avoided if the WSDL spec didn't have this rule in the first place :-) Note: I had to split my comment since stackoverflow accepts only 600 chars

Comment: @MeghanaReddy, I am still a bit confused. If you please, can you let me know what is the relationship you see between the names of the wsdl:input and wsdl:output elements, your Java and/or the XML on the wire? I wonder what am I missing here, since from what I can tell, there shouldn't be any.